# Vuetify / Mouseover does not work with v-system-nav

Tags: vuetify.js

Is there a way to make mouseover work with v-system-nav?  I have the following fiddle which demonstrates my issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/6dqfz3j2/1/

```
<div>
  <div id="content">
    <v-card @mouseover="abc">Mouseover this and look at the console. Mouseover works!</v-card>
    <v-system-bar @mouseover="abc">Mouseover this and look at the console. Mouseover does not work!</v-system-bar>
  </div>
</div>
...
methods: {
  abc() {
    console.log('hi');
  },
},
```

Is it a bug? Is there some property I can overwrite to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it. It needs to be @mouseover.native="abc" for the v-system-nav